# How to obtain cell tower data for iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone-5, core-telephony, ios6.1, signal-strength

I'm trying to get cell tower data with my iPhone 5. I've been testing with VAFieldTest (https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest). In the file VAFieldTestViewController.m (https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest/blob/master/Classes/VAFieldTestViewController.m) on Line 61, it always return 0 for iPhone 4S and 5.

After investigation, someone said Apple changed the modem (for iPhone 4S) Infineon Gold to Qualcomm mdm6610, and the iPhone 5 is using MDM9615M, thereby rendering the method call useless.

So, are there other methods to obtain the cell tower data for iPhone 5?

NOTE: this questions is specific for iPhone 5. It is not a duplicate of the other questions, because they work only up to iPhone 4.

Comment: Specifically, the method to obtain cell tower data is "_CTServerConnectionCellMonitorGetCellCount" and it always return 0, for iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haver you tried Apple's Core Telephony Framework.

CTCarrier Class Reference might be helpful.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596